# Node Express JS in IIS with HttpPlatformHandler

Tags: node.js, iis, httpplatformhandler

I'm getting an error `Cannot GET /nodetest/api/test` when trying to connect to my node app using IIS with HttpPlatformHandler

[image]

What I did is add my node app in `IIS` -> `Default Website` -> `Add Application` then
use the link http://localhost/nodetest/api/test to try the app

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
    return res.status(200).send('First Server');
})

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is listening to ${port}.....`);
})
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments=".\app.js">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Content of `nodetest` application pool
[image]

nodetest application settings
[image]

Comment: You provided too little information about your IIS setup. What is the physical path of that `web.config` file? What's the physical path you set in `Add Application` dialog? What's the name you gave to that new IIS application?

Comment: Hello, @LexLi I updated the content of my question. Thank you

Comment: I tried to make a test by creating the new Node app and adding your code to it. I run it locally and make sure it works. After that, I try to host it as an application under the Default site. I am getting errors but not the same as yours. Further, I host the site by creating a new website in the IIS. I noticed that it works fine. For testing purposes, could you try to host your site as a new website and see whether it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `app.js` as below, then it should work

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
    return res.status(200).send('First Server');
})

app.get('/nodetest/api/test', function(req, res){
    return res.status(200).send('as an IIS application');
})

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is listening to ${port}.....`);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case cure was in this line

*const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;*